# I want to validate AutoCompleteExtender Textbox only it allows Numbers

Tags: c#, javascript, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to validate Auto complete Extender Textbox with Numbers only. I wrote java script function Onchage event. it shows alert message and execute services.If i entered letters i dont want to services.

please help me.

**my code is:**

**my Javascript is:**

function mobileno() {

```
        var mobile = document.getElementById('<%=txtFormerMobile.ClientID %>').value;

        if (mobile == "") {
            alert("Please Enter Mobile Number");
            return false;
        }
        if (isNaN(mobile) || mobile.indexOf(" ") != -1) {

            document.getElementById('<%=txtFormerMobile.ClientID %>').value = "";
            alert("Enter numeric value");
            return false;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ValidationTextbox instead.
You can use parseInt() or parseFloat() function, depending on your need. Like this:

```
var query=getquerystring();
if(parseFloat(query) == NaN)
{
alert("query is a string");
}
else{
alert("query is numeric");
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can use regex pattern matching to see if the string matches what it should.

Comment: Validation is working. but it execute services if i entered character

Comment: If possible you can use executeService flag as boolean and depending on validation's result you can select whether to execute service or not.